# DisconnectEx not defined in mswsock.h

Tags: winapi, networking

In Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10, I am getting the error `error C3861: 'DisconnectEx': identifier not found`. According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737757(v=vs.85).aspx) on DisconnectEx, the function is defined in the header `mswsock.h`, but including that header does not work. Did the definition move elsewhere? Is there a mistake in the documentation?

Comment: Read the Note in the MSDN article: "The function pointer for the DisconnectEx function must be obtained at run time ...".  Declare the function pointer as  LPFN_DISCONNECTEX.

Comment: Related: [Where is ConnectEx defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967516/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DisconnectEx()` function itself is not declared in `mswsock.h`. Read the documentation again more carefully:

> **Note** The function pointer for the `DisconnectEx` function must be obtained at run time by making a call to the [WSAIoctl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741621.aspx) function with the `SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER` opcode specified. The input buffer passed to the `WSAIoctl` function must contain `WSAID_DISCONNECTEX`, a globally unique identifier (GUID) whose value identifies the `DisconnectEx` extension function. On success, the output returned by the `WSAIoctl` function contains a pointer to the `DisconnectEx` function. The `WSAID_DISCONNECTEX` GUID is defined in the `Mswsock.h` header file.

For example:

```
SOCKET s = ...;

...

GUID guidDisconnectEx = WSAID_DISCONNECTEX;
LPFN_DISCONNECTEX lpDisconnectEx = NULL;
DWORD cbBytesReturned = 0;    
WSAIoctl(s, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER, &guidDisconnectEx, sizeof(guidDisconnectEx), &lpDisconnectEx, sizeof(lpDisconnectEx), &cbBytesReturned, NULL, NULL);

...

if (lpDisconnectEx)
    lpDisconnectEx(s);
```

Comment: I'm confused why the socket `s` has to be passed into `WSAIoctl`. Can `DisconnectEx` only be called on that socket or can I disconnect other sockets also?

Comment: `DisconnectEx()` is a provider-specific extension, it is not part of the base Winsock API. By passing in a `SOCKET` handle, `WSAIoctl()` can query the function pointer from the provider that created the socket object. To use `DisconnectEx()`, the socket has to be created by Microsoft's WinSock2 provider, hence the note in the documentation: "*This function is a **Microsoft-specific extension** to the Windows Sockets specification*". There are other 3rd party socket providers in use in the world.

Comment: Using WinSock/2 on Windows *usually* uses Microsoft's provider (it is the default provider). But to *guarantee* that Microsoft's provider is used, if other providers are installed, you can request it via the `ProviderId` field of the [`WSAPROTOCOL_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741675.aspx) passed to [`WSASocket()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742212.aspx). [`WSAEnumProtocols()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741574.aspx) can enumerate the available providers and their implemented protocols.

Comment: You can call `DisconnectEx()` on *any* socket that is created with the Microsoft provider, but you need to start with a socket from that same provider in order to obtain the function pointer.  You can use a temporary socket, if you want. *Some* `WSAIoctl()` controls allow `INVALID_SOCKET` to be specified, but AFAIK `SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER` is not one of them.