# How to Get ConnectEx() pointer

Tags: c++, detours

I'm using **MS Detours** and I want get the *ConnectEx()* pointer but is load at run time, how to get pointer and use with **MS Detours**?

Comment: [Where is ConnectEx defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967516/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConnectEx()` is not an exported DLL function.  Per the [`ConnectEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606.aspx) documentation:

> **Note** **The function pointer for the `ConnectEx` function must be obtained at run time by making a call to the [`WSAIoctl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741621.aspx) function with the `SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER` opcode specified**. The input buffer passed to the `WSAIoctl` function must contain `WSAID_CONNECTEX`, a globally unique identifier (GUID) whose value identifies the `ConnectEx` extension function. On success, the output returned by the `WSAIoctl` function contains a pointer to the `ConnectEx` function. The `WSAID_CONNECTEX GUID` is defined in the `Mswsock.h` header file.

For example:

```
#include <winsock2.h> // Must be included before Mswsock.h
#include <mswsock.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

...

LPFN_CONNECTEX GetConnectExPtr(SOCKET s)
{
    LPFN_CONNECTEX lpConnectEx = NULL;
    GUID guid = WSAID_CONNECTEX;
    DWORD dwNumBytes = 0;
    WSAIoctl(s, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER, &guid, sizeof(guid), &lpConnectEx, sizeof(lpConnectEx), &dwNumBytes, NULL, NULL);
    return lpConnectEx;
}
```

Once you have a pointer to `ConnectEx()`, you can detour it.  Depending on the version of MSDetours you are using, you can either:

Use `DetourFunction()`:

```
#include <winsock2.h> // Must be included before Mswsock.h
#include <mswsock.h>
#include <detours.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")

...

LPFN_CONNECTEX Real_ConnectEx = NULL;
LPFN_CONNECTEX Trampoline_ConnectEx = NULL;

BOOL WINAPI MyConnectEx(SOCKET s, const struct sockaddr *name, int namelen, PVOID lpSendBuffer, DWORD dwSendDataLength, LPDWORD lpdwBytesSent, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
    // do something...
    return Trampoline_ConnectEx(s, name, namelen, lpSendBuffer, dwSendDataLength, lpdwBytesSent, lpOverlapped);
}

...

SOCKET s = ...;
Real_ConnectEx = GetConnectExPtr(s);
if (Real_ConnectEx)
{
    Trampoline_ConnectEx = (LPFN_CONNECTEX) DetourFunction((PBYTE)Real_ConnectEx, (PBYTE)MyConnectEx);
}

...

if (Trampoline_ConnectEx)
    DetourRemoveTrampoline(Trampoline_ConnectEx);
```

Use `DetourAttach/Ex()`:

```
#include <winsock2.h> // Must be included before Mswsock.h
#include <mswsock.h>
#include <detours.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "detoured.lib")

...

LPFN_CONNECTEX Real_ConnectEx = NULL;
LPFN_CONNECTEX Trampoline_ConnectEx = NULL;

BOOL WINAPI MyConnectEx(SOCKET s, const struct sockaddr *name, int namelen, PVOID lpSendBuffer, DWORD dwSendDataLength, LPDWORD lpdwBytesSent, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
    // do something...
    return Trampoline_ConnectEx(s, name, namelen, lpSendBuffer, dwSendDataLength, lpdwBytesSent, lpOverlapped);
}

...

SOCKET s = ...;
Real_ConnectEx = GetConnectExPtr(s);
if (Real_ConnectEx)
{
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

    // using DetourAttach()...
    Trampoline_ConnectEx = Real_ConnectEx;
    DetourAttach((PVOID*)&Trampoline_ConnectEx, MyConnectEx);

    // using DetourAttachEx()...
    // DetourAttachEx(&Real_ConnectEx, MyConnectEx, (PDETOUR_TRAMPOLINE*)&Trampoline_ConnectEx, NULL, NULL);

    DetourTransactionCommit();
}

...

if ((Real_ConnectEx) && (Trampoline_ConnectEx))
{    
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

    // if using DetourAttach()...
    DetourDetach((PVOID*)&Trampoline_ConnectEx, MyConnectEx);

    // if using DetourAttachEx()...
    // DetourDetach((PVOID*)&Real_ConnectEx, MyConnectEx);

    DetourTransactionCommit();
}
```

Comment: I have added an example for you (you could have done a web search to find this information, it is readily available, and has been posted on StackOverflow several times).

Comment: thank so much, I found also that code, but i dunno how to apply into MS Destour.